# Magento 2 How to get all images of a product?

Tags: magento2, product, image

How to get all images of a specific product in Magento 2?

Comment: You just want to dump all the images somewhere in the web? Be more specific please. :D

Comment: In which file you want to get all Images?

Comment: `$product->getMediaGalleryEntries()`

Comment: `$product->getMediaGalleryEntries() ` returns all files by `->getFile()` saved in a product gallery, including hidden images.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
<?php
    $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
    $product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($_product->getId());        
    $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();
    foreach($images as $child){ ?>
        <img src="<?php echo $child->getUrl(); ?>" >
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Can I actually do this without objectManager?

Comment: $_product is undefined...

Comment: $productid=12;
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productid);  

You want to give product id. You want to fetch products and pass product ids.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is too broad. you didn't specify where or how do you want to get images. if you want to show all images in custom slider then try below code:

```
<ul id="image-gallery" class="gallery list-unstyled cS-hidden">

            <?php $images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages(); ?>
            <?php foreach ($images as $_image) : ?>

                <li data-src="">
                    <a href=""><img alt="Rootways Extension" class="img-responsive" src="<?= $_image->getUrl();?>"></a>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get all images by below code to default gallery.phtml file

```
<?php
foreach($block->getGalleryImages() as $image){ ?>
    <img src="<?php echo $image->getData('medium_image_url') ?>">
<?php } 
?>
```

Comment: but I need only the images of specific product, not all images of all products

Answer (score 1):

**Try this:**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$directory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\Filesystem\DirectoryList');
$mediaPath = $directory->getPath('media');

$product_id = 10;
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($product_id);

$galleryReadHandler = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Gallery\ReadHandler');
$galleryReadHandler->execute($product);
$images = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

foreach($images as $image){
 $temp = $mediaPath."/catalog/product".$image->getFile();
 echo "<pre>"; print_r($temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below code. If you want to show product images category wise then use below code.

```
<?php $catid = $block->getCurrentCategory()->getId(); ?>
<?php 
$objectManager =  \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();        
$appState = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Framework\App\State');
//$appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
$categoryFactory = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryFactory');
$categoryHelper = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Category');
$categoryRepository = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Model\CategoryRepository');
$storeManager = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface');
$mediaUrl =  $storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(\Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
if ($catid == 3) 
  {
    $categoryId = $catid;
    $category = $categoryFactory->create()->load($categoryId);
    $categoryProducts = $category->getProductCollection()
                             ->addAttributeToSelect('*');
 ?>
 <div id="Coverflow">
     <ul class="flip-items">
        <?php foreach($categoryProducts as $product): ?>
         <li>
            <a href="<?php echo $product->getProductUrl() ?>">
                 <img src="<?php echo $mediaUrl.'catalog/product/'.$product->getImage() ?>" alt=""/>
             </a>
         </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
     </ul>
</div>
<?php } ?>
```

I hope it will help you.

Comment: At least 70% of the code here you don't need.

Comment: this is work for me